# Traktor s2 controller and Kaoss Pad integration

Tags: midi

Anyone know if its possible to hook up a Kaoss pad to a traktor s2 midi controller?

Comment: What do you mean "hook up"?  In what way?

Comment: what Josh said. more info needed, but I'm getting an s4 here soon and am going to do what I think you're asking about, so I will let you know then

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. If I want to loop output from the kaoss pad through the s2. There isnt any input on an s2, but there is a mic input, so wonder if I could use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the audio output from the Kaoss Pad and send it into the S2's input, however you may find the volume it's not exactly what you want.

The usual way you would do this is use a preamp to match impedance, to reduce losses, and to set the volume on the S2 input to a suitable level.